# Regular expression for accent-insensitive match

Tags: jquery, regex, unicode

I have a list of author names in Spanish, I implemented a search functionality using simple reg ex.

But how do I match English characters with Spanish characters ?

If I am searching using Ant, it gives the result 'Antón, Arturo'
But if I use 'Anto' it  doesn't show up.

How can I match both, 'o' and 'ó' ?

This is the jquery code I am using:

```
var patt = new RegExp(searchValue);
var res  = patt.test($(val).find('.itemName').text().toLowerCase());
if (res) { $(val).show(); }
```

Please help.

Comment: What regex engine are you using? On which programming language? Some engines/languages have specific commands for locales

Comment: This is the jquery code I am using                                                           var patt = new RegExp(searchValue);
                        var res = patt.test($(val).find('.itemName').text().toLowerCase());
                        if (res) {
                            $(val).show();
                        }

Comment: JavaScript, as far as I know, doesn't have a built-in mechanism to deal with Unicode normalization. This probably requires some sort of Unicode database to map the characters and build the regex.